# How would you create a sql query that uses a merge join?

Tags: mysql, sql

**Write a SQL query that could produce this query plan.**

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE Slot(
    sid int PRIMARY KEY,
    wall VARCHAR(30),
    x float,
    y float
)

CREATE TABLE Placement(
    rid int REFERENCES Route(rid),
    hid int REFERENCES Hold(hid),
    sid int REFERENCES Slot(sid),
    PRIMARY KEY(rid, hid, sid)
)
```

Would this sql query be able to produce this plan?

```
Select *
FROM Placement P, Slot S
WHERE P.sid = S.sid
```

Comment: SQL is a *declaritive* language, you describe *what* you want, not *how*. Saying that, *typically*, the optimiser will choose a merge join when there are a large number of rows being joined on keys that are both *sorted*.

Comment: *side note, see [Bad habbits](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Please check your DBMS name carefully - your SQL code is wrong for MySQL.

Comment: @Akina What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that both plan screenshot and SQL code looks like specific to MS SQL (SQL Server), not MySQL which is absolutely different DBMS...

Answer (score 0):

Do a `FROM` table then `JOIN` anotherTable and then the condition after `ON`

```
Select *
FROM Placement P
INNER JOIN Slot S
ON P.sid = S.sid
```